# What is the best time for a short walk before or after the meal?

Tags: exercise, walking

I was wondering what is the best time for a short brisk walk, before or after a heavy meal. I searched for it but I found some people online suggesting to walk after the meal citing some of the research papers while others were the exact opposite and suggested walking before the meal.

Comment: I think the biggest factor would be the one that actually allows you to do it and be consistent.